# Give me a water. Is this expression possible in conversation?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I know that "water" or "a glass(cup) of water" is the right expression.

But I'm wondering.

If someone says to you that "Give me ***a*** water, please.", what would you think that means?

Comment: At a bar, this is commonly used a concise way of ordering a drink. For multiple drinks you might just say "Two waters/juices/beers/whiskies please." Note that you would probably not say it with a drink where the size is not obvious, e.g. "Two wines please." is uncommon, it would more likely be "Two glasses of wine please" or "Two bottles of wine please".

Comment: "A water" can also be an event. For example, you might give your flowers a water from your watering can. If you're trying to ask someone to pour water on you, "give me a water" is a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: Not sure if it's called that in English-speaking countries, but the measuring instrument - containing a couple of glass vials with water and an air-bubble in a metal or plastic frame - used to see if something (like a floor) is level (ie. completely horizontal) is called "*water*" - so "give me a water" would be a perfectly good way to ask for one.

Comment: This is an increasingly common way to refer to "a bottle of water".  If there are bottles of water in the room, you might say: "hand me *a* water".  It works just like 'beer' as in it doesn't make sense to say "hand me beer".  You'd say "hand me *a* beer"

Comment: @Baard Kopperud: In English that thing is called a "bubble level", "spirit level", or usually just "level" in conversation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your example, "a water" probably means a single serving of water.

If we use the indefinite article **a** with a normally uncountable noun, we usually do it to mean one of two things:

1. A certain *kind* of that noun.
2. A single *instance* or *serving* of that noun, such as a packaged container of it from a shop or a serving at a restaurant.

Here's an example for each case, respectively:

> In Mexico I tasted a water unlike any I'd drunk before.

(To clarify, that's the *past perfect* used to mean that when I drank it, I *had never drunk* a water like that before.)

> I was thirsty so I stopped at a store and bought a water.

You might also hear something like this:

> I'm thirsty.  I think I'll buy some juice.  How much is a juice?

Again, that's referring to a single packaged juice, usually a single serving.  If I'm talking about buying a large container of juice to keep in my fridge, I'll probably just refer to it as "juice" or "some juice".  But if I were telling my wife (if I had one) to buy two large containers of juice, I might say:  "When you're at the store, buy two juices."  I could say "some juice", but it's understood when I say "two" that I want to units/containers, and this is using "juice" in a countable way.

Comment: One more comment about "buy two juices" vs. "buy some juice": The latter ("buy some juice") says nothing about how much juice to buy, whereas the former allows us to specify a quantity. (As you say in your answer, it's assumed that the person you are talking to will know what kind of container we are talking about – either through previous experience, or prior conversation.)

Comment: This is an amazing answer beyond my expectations. Thank you very much.

Comment: But of course, in "they stock three juices, buy the pineapple", the sense is not "a portion of", but "a kind of".

Comment: Yes, that's an example of the first reason, "A certain kind of that noun".  All fishes are fish, all fish are fish of a fish, and all fish contain fish.

Comment: Be careful of "a Coke" in Texas.  Ask for a Coke and then they'll ask what kind and you can reply with Mr Pibb, Mountain Dew etc...

Comment: @AbraCadaver What do you say if you want what is elsewhere called "a Coke", in Texas?

Comment: @Andres: I'm assuming "Pepsi", "Coca-Cola", or simply "cola". Pop, soda, soda pop, cola, fizzy drink, soft drink, carbonated beverage... these things go by some many names it's ridiculous.

Comment: @AndresRiofrio You would ask for a Coke and when they ask what kind you would say Coke.  Kind of strange but it happens.